# pandas does not append to df as it should of each line of iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that does not behave. Please help me train it!

I need for each of my iterations that goes through to the deepest nested 'if' statement (that satisfies all my requirements), to be appended do my df 'df_comp_KPIs'.

Why does this code not work?

Any ideas

```
import time
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4


start = time.time()     # Start script timer

# Creating the df that will save my results in the Yahoo KPI iterations
#global df_comp_KPIs
df_comp_KPIs = pd.DataFrame()  #columns = ('Ticker','Mark.Cap','PriceToBook','PEG5','TrailPE12Mo','DeptToEquit.')

ofInterest = ['AAN', 'ANF', 'ANCX', 'ACE', 'ATVI', 'AET', 'AGCO', 'ATSG', 'AWH', 'ALL', 'AFAM', 'ALJ']

evenBetter = []

# add some more to powers as necessary
powers = {'M': 10 ** 6, 'B': 10 ** 9, 'T': 10 ** 12}

# Convert the string from Market Cap col to float.    
def stringNoToFloat(s):
    try:
        power = s[-1]
        return float(s[:-1]) * powers[power]
    except TypeError:
        return s

#df.applymap(stringNoToFloat)

def yahoostats(ticker):

    try:
        print ('doing',ticker)
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s='+ticker
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = bs4(page)
        page.close()
        # Lookup pbr and return the next 'td' tag-content
        mcap = soup.find(text='Market Cap (intraday)').findNext('td').string
#        print('Market Cap:', mcap)
        pbr = float(soup.find(text='Price/Book (mrq):').findNext('td').string)
#        print('Ticker %s, Price to book ratio:  %1.2f' %(ticker, float(pbr)))  # format 2 dig.
#        print()

        if float(pbr) < 3:
#            print ('price to book ratio:',ticker,pbr)
            PEG5 = float(soup.find(text='PEG Ratio (5 yr expected)').findNext('td').string)
#            print('Ticker %s, PEG Ratio (5 yr expected):  %1.2f' %(ticker, PEG5))  # format 2 dig.

            if 0 < float(PEG5) < 3:
                #print 'PEG forward 5 years',PEG5
                DE = float(soup.find(text='Total Debt/Equity (mrq):').findNext('td').string)
#                print('Ticker %s, Total Debt/Equity (mrq):  %1.2f' %(ticker, DE))  # format 2 dig.
#
#                #if 0 < float(DE) < 2:
#
                PE12 = float(soup.find(text='Trailing P/E (ttm, intraday):').findNext('td').string)
#                print ('Trailing PE (12mo):', PE12)
                if float(PE12) < 15:
                    evenBetter.append(ticker)
                    df_comp_KPIs = df_comp_KPIs.append({'Ticker':ticker,'Mark.Cap':mcap,'PriceToBook':pbr,'PEG5':PEG5,'TrailPE12Mo':PE12,'DeptToEquit':DE}, ignore_index = True)  #
                    df_comp_KPIs = df_comp_KPIs.sort(['PriceToBook','PEG5'], ascending=[1,1])  # , ignore_index=True

                    print('____________________________')
                    print('')
                    print(ticker,'meets requirements')
                    print('Market Cap (intraday):', mcap)
                    print('price to book:',pbr)
                    print('PEG forward 5 years',PEG5)
                    print('Trailing PE (12mo):',PE12)
                    print('Debt to Equity:',DE)
                    print('____________________________')

        # saving ticker KPIs to csv #
        df_comp_KPIs.to_csv('df_company_KPIs.csv')

    except Exception as e:
        print ('failed in the main loop:',str(e))
        pass

    return mcap, pbr, PEG5, PE12, DE

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for eachticker in ofInterest:
        yahoostats(eachticker)
#        time.sleep(.05)
    print(evenBetter)
    print()
    print('Company screener finished in %.1f seconds' %(time.time()-start))
    # Convert string with MarketCap to float in one go on the mcap col in df
    df_comp_KPIs['Mark.Cap'].applymap(stringNoToFloat)
```

Comment: You'll have more luck if you edit your question so that it actually asks a specific question.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the essential bits that reproduce your error, there is a lot of irrelevant code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It appears I ended up with this error because of a missing global def of my df. So the code could not see the df created outside the function.

So the beffing of my function should look like this instead of the above:

```
def yahoostats(ticker):

    global df_comp_KPIs

    try:
        print ('doing',ticker)
        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s='+ticker
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

This solves the issue and I can alter, call, or do anything else with my df.

I found the answer here:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python